# get list of all the tasks of a remote windows machine from linux machine

Tags: linux, windows, remote-server, powershell-remoting

Is it possible to get list of tasks running in a remote windows box from linux machine ?
we can use `tasklist` with remote switch but you have do that from another windows machine. is there a way to access same information from linux machine.